# How do these definitions of factorization algebra compare?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, quantum-field-theory, limits-and-colimits, higher-algebra

### Question

Several sources define (homotopy) factorization algebras in a seemingly
different manner (I am looking at [CG], [Gi], and
[CFM].) I wish to know how they compare with each other.

I apologize for the lengthy post. If you are familiar with factorization algebra, you can probably skip the section entitled "Preliminary Definitions."

---

### Preliminary Definitions

To be absolutely clear, let us start from the definition of prefactorization algebras.
For definiteness, I will consider the case where the target category
is the category $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$ of cochain
complexes over a Grothendieck abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Let
$M$ be an $n$-manifold.

> **Definition**(Prefactorization algebra) A prefactorization algebra on
> $M$ (with values in $\mathcal{C}$) consists of the following data:
>
> - For each open subset $U\subset M$, a cochain complex $FU\in\mathcal{C}$,
> - For each collection $U_{1},\dots,U_{k},V\subset M$
>   of open subsets of $M$ such that $U_{i}\cap U_{j}=\emptyset$ and
>   $\bigcup_{i}U_{i}\subset V$, a map
>   $$
>   m_{U_{1},\dots,U_{k};V}:\bigotimes_{i=1}^{k}FU_{i}\to FV.
>   $$
>
> These data are required to satisfy the following conditions:
>
> - For each open set $U\subset M$, the map $m_{U,U}$ is the identity
>   map.
> - For each collection of open sets $U_{11},\dots,U_{k_{1}1},\dots,U_{1l},\dots,U_{k_{l}l},V_{1},\dots,V_{l},W\subset M$
>   such that $U_{ij}\cap U_{i'j}=\emptyset$, $V_{j}\cap V_{j'}=\emptyset$,
>   and $\bigcup_{i}U_{ij}\subset V_{j}$ and $\bigcup_{j}V_{j}\subset W$,
>   we have
>   $$
>   m_{U_{11},\dots,U_{k_{l}l};W}=m_{V_{1},\dots,V_{l};W}\circ\bigotimes_{j=1}^{l}m_{U_{1j},\dots,U_{k_{j}j};V_{j}}.
>   $$

To state various definitions of factorization algebras, we also need some definitions on covers.

> **Definition**(Weiss cover and factorizing cover) Let $\mathcal{U}$ be
> an open cover of $M$.
>
> - We call $\mathcal{U}$ a Weiss cover if for each finite set $S\subset M$,
>   there is an element $U\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $S\subset U$.
> - We call $\mathcal{U}$ a factorizing cover if for each finite subset
>   $S\subset M$, there is a finite subset $\alpha\subset\mathcal{U}$
>   of pairwise disjoint open sets such that $S\subset\bigcup_{V\in\alpha}V$.

---

### Definitions of Factorization Algebra

We now look at the definitions of (homotopy) factorization algebras
in the sources cited above. Let $F$ be a prefactorization algebra
on $M$.

> **Definition (1), found in [CG, 6.1.4].** We call $F$ a factorization algebra if
> for each Weiss cover $\mathcal{U}$ of an open
> set $U\subset M$, the map
> $$
> T\to FU
> $$
> is a quasi-isomorphism, where $T$ denotes the totalization of the
> normalized chain complex in $\cal C$ (regarded as a cochain complex
> in $\cal C$ concentrated in negative degrees) associated with the
> simplicial object $\{\bigoplus_{U_{0},\dots,U_{n}\in\mathcal{U}}F\left(U_{0}\cap\cdots\cap U_{n}\right)\}_{n\geq0}$.

> **Definition (2), found in [Gi, p. 36].** We call $F$ a factorization algebra if
> for each factorizing cover $\cal U$ of an open
> set $U\subset M$, the map
> $$
> T\to FU
> $$
> is a quasi-isomorphism, where the object $T\in\cal C$ is defined
> in the following manner: Let $P\mathcal{U}$ denote the set of finite
> subsets $\alpha\subset\mathcal{U}$ consisting of pairwise disjoint
> open sets. Given elements $\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n}\in P\mathcal{U}$,
> we will write
> $$
> F\left(\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n}\right)=\bigotimes_{U_{j}\in\alpha_{j}}F\left(\bigcap_{j=0}^{n}U_{j}\right).
> $$
> The objects $\{\bigoplus_{\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n}\in P\mathcal{U}}F(\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n})\}_{n\geq0}$
> form a simplicial objet in $\cal C$. The object $T\in\cal C$ is
> the totalization of the Moore complex of this simplicial object (regarded
> as a cochain complex in $\cal C$ concentrated in negative degrees).

> **Definition (3), found in [CFM, Definition 2.2].** We call $F$ a factorization algebra if for each open set $U\subset M$ and each Weiss cover
> $\mathcal{U}$ of $U$, the map $$
> \operatorname{hocolim}_{\alpha\subset\mathcal{U}\text{
> finite}}F\left(\bigcap_{V\in\alpha}V\right)\to FU $$ is a
> quasi-isomorphism, and moreover for each pairwise disjoint open sets
> $U_{1},\dots,U_{k}\subset M$, the map
> $m_{U_{1},\dots,U_{k};\bigcup_{i}U_{i}}$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

---

### Comments

I am unfamiliar with the computation of homotopy colimits of cochain
complexes, but looking at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194010/reference-for-homotopy-colimits-of-cochain-complexes-via-totalization-of-dou), I suspect that
the object $T$ in Definitions (1) and (2) are homotopy colimits of
the corresponding simplicial object. So they are similar in the sense
that they both use simplicial objects, but they differ in their choices
of covers.

I am perplexed by the sudden appearance of the simplicial objects in these definitions; perhaps knowing something about homotopy colimits of cochain complexes might help, but the only reference I have on that topic is [CG], which I found not so helpful in explaining why the simplicial objects in (1) and (2) appeared.)

Definition (3) looks like a hybrid of (1) and (2) because
it uses Weiss covers and somehow tries to incorporate the information
of multiplicative structures of $F$ in the definition.

All these definitions look different to me.

---

**References**

[CG] Costello, K., Gwilliam, O. (2017). Factorization Algebras
in Quantum Field Theory: Volume 1.

[CFM] Carmona,V., Flores,R., and Fernando Muro. (2022). A model
structure for locally constant factorization algebras. arxiv.2107.14174

[Gi] Grégory Ginot. (2014). Notes on factorization algebras, factorization
homology and applications. arxiv.1307.5213

Comment: (I have suggested an edit and it is in the review queue. Please disregard it, I believe there should instead be a different edit to make Definition 1 match [CG, p.212].)

Comment: Your suggestion for Definition 3 is totally right, and I accepted it. But your suggestion for Definition 1 is probably off the mark. If we take all $U_i$ distinct, then the resulting collection of objects will not be a simplicial object, but only a semisimplicial object. (Notice that I am taking the *normalized* chain complex, which kills the degenerate part.) Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that Definition 2 and Definition 3 are equivalent. This involves that Definition 2 implies that F is multiplicative ("for each pairwise disjoint open sets
$U_{1},\dots,U_{k}\subset M$, the map
$m_{U_{1},\dots,U_{k};\bigcup_{i}U_{i}}$ is a quasi-isomorphism"), that every Weiss cover can be refined by a cover consisting of disjoint unions of small balls, and that (as you say) that there is a relationship between homotopy colimits and simplicial objects.

(In a cocomplete category every colimit can be written as a specific coequalizer of two coproducts.
In an \infty-category like the derived \infty-category of a field, this generalizes to a colimit over a simplicial object.
There is an appendix in [CG] which explains parts of this story and contains some references - not sure if you already saw this and wanted more or not.)

Definition 1 + multiplicative is equivalent to Definition 3.

The examples in [CG] satisfy Definition 1 but most of them are not multiplicative for $A$ the category of vector spaces with the ordinary tensor product of vector spaces.
Therefore Definition 1 is not equivalent to Definition 3.
These examples are multiplicative if one uses a completed versions of the tensor product, but then one would need to do homological algebra with some flavor of complete vector spaces which usually do not form an abelian category.
Maybe what one should do is use the symmetric monoidal category of liquid vector spaces, because they have a good tensor product and form an abelian category at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I am happy to hear that the various
definitions are not so distant to each other. May I ask you which
diagram's homotopy colimit do the objects $T$ appearing in Definition
(1) and (2) correspond? (My guess is that they are $\operatorname{hocolim}_{U\in\mathcal{U}}F(U)$
and $\operatorname{hocolim}_{\alpha\in P\mathcal{U}}\bigotimes_{U\in\alpha}F\left(U\right)$,
respecitvely, but I have no tools available to justify my guess. I am
aware of the appendix of CG, but the formula for the homotopy colimits
there gives slightly different simplicial objects.)

Comment: Sorry for taking such a long time to accept your answer. It took me a while to verify that everything was in place.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here is the full story, which confirms what is written in Daniel Bruegmann's answer. In what follows, I will work with a fixed
prefactorization algebra $F$ and an $n$-manifold $M$. I will make
use of the fact that the homotopy colimits of simplicial (co)chain complexes are given by the (direct sum) totalization of the associated double complex; see my note [Ara]
for a detailed account on this. Our argument will also make use of the fact that reindexing by homotopy final functors preserves homotopy colimits; [ArØr] is a good reference for this.

---

### A FEW REMARKS

- Definition (2) does not quite make sense. Indeed, as soon as $\mathcal{U}$
  contains some element $U$, we would need a map $I=F(\emptyset,\{U\})\to F(\{U\})$
  corresponding to the face map $d_{0}$; but I don't know where such
  a map comes from (except when $F(\emptyset)=I$). I will therefore
  redefine $F(\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n})$ in Definition (2) as
  $$
  F(\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n})=F\left(\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}O(\alpha_{i})\right),
  $$
  where we set $O(\alpha)=\bigcup_{V\in\alpha}V$ for each $\alpha\in P\mathcal{U}$.
- In Definition (3), we should index the homotopy colimits by {*}nonempty{*}
  subsets of $\mathcal{U}$. Otherwise, the homotopy colimit will just
  be $FU$.

---

### THE EQUIVALENCES

We will prove the following:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $F$ be a prefactorization algebra on $M$. Suppose that, for
> each finite set $U_{1},\dots,U_{k}$ of open sets of $M$, the map
> $\bigotimes_{i=1}^{k}F(U_{i})\to F(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}U_{i})$ is a
> quasi-isomorphism. Then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (A) $F$ is a factorization algebra in the sense of Definition (1).
>
> (B) $F$ is a factorization algebra in the sense of Definition (2) (or rather, its modified version explained in the above remark)
>
> (C) $F$ is a factorization algebra in the sense of Definition (3).
>
> (D) Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a Weiss cover of an open set $U\subset M$
> such that, for each $V\in\mathcal{U}$, every open subset of $V$
> belongs to $\mathcal{U}$. Then the map
> $$
> \operatorname{hocolim}_{V\in\mathcal{U}}F(V)\to F(U)
> $$
> is a quasi-isomorphism.

We need a lemma:

> **Lemma 2.**
> Let $S$ be a nonempty set. Let $\mathcal{X}(S)$ denote
> the category whose objects are the finite nonempty sequences $\left(x_{0},\dots,x_{n}\right)$
> of elements of $S$, and whose morphism $\left(x_{0},\dots,x_{n}\right)\to\left(y_{0},\dots,y_{m}\right)$
> is a poset map $u:[m]\to[n]$ such that $x_{u(i)}=y_{i}$ for every
> $0\leq i\leq m$. The nerve of $\mathcal{X}(S)$ is weakly contractible.

(**Proof of Lemma 2.**) The category $\mathcal{X}(S)$ is the category of elements of the
functor $S^{[\bullet]}:\mathbf{\Delta}^{\mathrm{op}}\to\mathsf{Set}$
defined by $[n]\mapsto S^{[n]}$. By Thomason's homotopy colimit theorem,
the simplicial set $N(\mathcal{C})$ has the weak homotopy type of the homotopy colimit of the composite $\mathbf{\Delta}^{\mathrm{op}}\xrightarrow{S^{[\bullet]}}\mathsf{Set}\hookrightarrow\mathsf{sSet}$.
The latter is given by the diagonal of the corresponding bisimplicial
set, which, in this case, is the simplicial set $S^{[\bullet]}$.
It will therefore suffice to show that the simplicial set $S^{[\bullet]}$
is weakly contractible. We claim that $S^{[\bullet]}$ is a contractible
Kan complex. Observe that, given a simplicial set $X$, defining a
map of simplicial sets $X\to S^{[\bullet]}$ is equivalent to defining
a set map $X_{0}\to S$. So the simplicial set has the extension property
for the inclusion $\partial\Delta^{n}\subset\Delta^{n}$ for every
$n>0$. Since $S$ is nonempty, the simplicial set $S^{[\bullet]}$
has the extension property for the inclusion $\partial\Delta^{0}\subset\Delta^{0}$. $\blacksquare$

(**Proof of Proposition 1.**)

**(A)$\implies$(D):** Let $\mathcal{U}$ be as in
(D). The simplicial object $\left\{ \bigoplus_{U_{0},\dots,U_{n}\in\mathcal{U}}F\left(\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}U_{i}\right)\right\} _{n\geq0}$
is a left Kan extension of the composite $\mathcal{X}(\mathcal{U})\xrightarrow{\varphi}\mathcal{U}\xrightarrow{F}\mathcal{C}$
along the projection $\mathcal{X}\to\mathbf{\Delta}^{\mathrm{op}}$,
where the functor $\varphi$ is given by $\varphi(U_{0},\dots,U_{n})=\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}U_{i}$.
Therefore, condition (A) implies that the map $\operatorname{hocolim}_{(U_{0},\dots,U_{n})\in\mathcal{X}}F(\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}U_{i})\to FU$
is a quasi-isomorphism. It will therefore suffice to show that $\varphi$
is homotopy final, which follows from Lemma 2.

**(D)$\implies$(A):** Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a Weiss
cover of an open set $U\subset M$. Arguing as in the previous paragraph,
it will suffice to show that the map $\operatorname{hocolim}_{(U_{0},\dots,U_{n})\in\mathcal{X}}F(\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}U_{i})\to FU$
is a quasi-isomorphism. Let $\overline{\mathcal{U}}$ denote the set
of open subsets of elements of $\mathcal{U}$, and define $\varphi:\mathcal{X}(\mathcal{U})\to\overline{\mathcal{U}}$
as in the previous paragraph. By Lemma 2, the functor $\varphi$ is
homotopy final, so condition (D) implies that the map $\operatorname{hocolim}_{(U_{0},\dots,U_{n})\in\mathcal{X}}F(\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}U_{i})\to FU$
is a quasi-isomorphism, as claimed.

**(D)$\implies$(C):** Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a Weiss
cover of an open set $U\subset M$. Let $P$ denote the set of finite
nonempty subsets of $\mathcal{U}$, and let $\overline{\mathcal{U}}$
denote the set of open subsets of elements of $\mathcal{U}$. The
assignment $\alpha\mapsto\bigcap_{V\in\alpha}V$ determines a map
$\varphi:P^{\mathrm{op}}\to\overline{\mathcal{U}}$. To complete the
proof, it suffices to show that $\varphi$ is homotopy final, which
is trivial.

**(C)$\implies$(D):** This is similar to (C)$\implies$(D).

**(B)$\implies$(D):** Let $\mathcal{U}$ be as in
(D). Arguing as in the proof of (A)$\implies$(D) (and noting that
$\mathcal{U}$ is a factorizing cover), we are reduced to showing
that the functor $\mathcal{X}(P\mathcal{U})\to\mathcal{U}$ defined
by $(\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n})\mapsto\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}O(\alpha_{i})$
is homotopy final. This follows from Lemma 2.

**(D)$\implies$(B):** Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a factorizing
cover of an open set $U\subset M$. Let $\mathcal{V}$ denote the
set of all open subsets of the topological spaces $\{U(\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in P\mathcal{U}}$.
Note that $\mathcal{V}$ is a Weiss cover. Arguing as in the proof
of (D)$\implies$(A), we are reduced to showing that the functor $\mathcal{X}(P\mathcal{U})\to\mathcal{V}$
defined by $(\alpha_{0},\dots,\alpha_{n})\mapsto\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}O(\alpha_{i})$
is homotopy final. This is a consequence of Lemma 2. $\blacksquare$

---

### REFERENCES

[Ara] Arakawa, K. (2023). Homotopy Limits and Homotopy Colimits of Chain Complexes. [arxiv.2310.00201](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.00201)

[ArØr] Arkhipov, S., Ørsted, S. Homotopy (co)limits via homotopy (co)ends in general combinatorial model categories. [arxiv.1807.03266](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03266)